# swift: Retrieving images from "Parse"

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, backend

Im new in Parse(parse.com). I have such kind of table in parse.com:
[image]

And I wanna retrieve these 3 images and put are in table view row. And here is my code:

```
class LeaguesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var leagues = [PFObject]() {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    var leaguesImage = [NSData]() {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadData()
        tableView.registerClass(LeaguesTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ReusableCell")   
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return leagues.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 160
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ReusableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LeaguesTableViewCell

        cell.leagueImage.image = UIImage(data: leaguesImage[indexPath.row])
        cell.leagueNameLabel.text = leagues[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String

        return cell
        }

    // MARK: Parse

    func loadData() {

        let query = PFQuery(className: "Leagues")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) in
            if( objects != nil && error == nil) {

                // List of leagues
                for i in objects! {
                    self.leagues.append(i)

                    // Retrieve images
                    let imageFile = i["image"] as? PFFile
                    imageFile!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            if let imageData = imageData {
                                self.leaguesImage.append(imageData)

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } else if error != nil {
                print("Error is: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code and from my point of view is everything is ok. But I have error: Index out of the range. My leaguesImages array is empty. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `leagues` and `leaguesImages` are getting out of sync. Once you retrieve the array from Parse, you are adding the `leagues` immediately, but `leaguesImages` are only being added after `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` completes.

Instead of downloading the image data right away and storing it in a separate array, I would add a `leagues` property to your custom cell, and in there I would download the data and apply the image.

Populating an array like you are populating the `leaguesImages` array is a bad idea when the order matters, because you don't know which one will finish downloading first, maybe the second league image is the smallest, and it will be set as the image for the first league. (PS: image size is not the only thing that dictates how long a download will take)

Comment: thanks for your answer but i don't understand what you mean in this sentences: "I would add a leagues property to your custom cell, and in there I would download the data and apply the image."

Comment: Add a `var league: PFObject` property to your cell, and fetch the data in the `didSet` of that property.

Comment: whats is mean add property to cell? Pls, can u fully answers. Im new in mobile development

Comment: Sorry dude, I don't have the time or the will to guide you through the whole thing, properties are something you should fully understand before attempting what you are attempting, or you should at least be willing to research what you don't know yet. A big part of being a programmer is finding the answers, not just expecting people to give them to you.